# install angular2 on visual studio 2015 html application typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015

how can I install angular 2 on typescript

> **[Html application with typescript]**

I tried to install it with

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

or like [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html) said 
but got nothing :(
 Not using ASP Core or MVC 5 .. just html typescript project with angular 2 .. I cannot find any resource to how do it .. any help please :)
thank you

Comment: You typed it where? And how is it related to VS 2015? Which node and npm versions are you running? And what do you mean by *"got nothing"* - at least you should have gotten error messages (or other output)

Comment: I typed it in the folder of the project, Node v:6.10, npm v:3.10.10, the errors showed on import {Component, View, bootstrap} from "@angular2/Core"; and it was Cannot find module '@angular2/Core'

Comment: So you have a project already set up? Also that command only installs the Angular-CLI, it does not install any libraries or set up a project on its own - the link in your question details this quite well

Comment: ok.. now how can i open it on vs 2015 (not vs code) .. I tried to Open website and on run it gives me error: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  
This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS

Comment: An Angular2 application is not just a simple website - you need to build it first so it can be opened in a browser. You should read the Angular documentation and familiarize yourself with the way it works, including samples such as [this one](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html)

Comment: I am sorry, but that is not what I need .. I want to run angular 2 application on [[vs 2015 Html application with TypeScript]]

Comment: Maybe this help any one, the solution is http://www.tonylunt.com/angular-2/angular-2-in-visual-studio-2015/